# Collapsing Action Bar but only shows when RecyclerView is fully displaying the first item

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a page that has a collapsing action bar effect, similar to this: http://xmodulo.com/hide-show-toolbar-scrolling-android.html. But I want the action bar to only show when the list is already showing the first item, not immediately whenever i scroll down. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It depends at you implementation. Can you please mention how you are achieving this effect ? Using a library or handling every thing in your code?

Comment: the implementation is linked in my question, that's how i'm achieving the effect.

Comment: Currently there is no way to achieve that effect. If you  specify app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"  in place of app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" to you toolbar, it will never enter back. One way to achieve that is Use Toolbar as a header to List view or Grid View. This way it will scroll out and in the way you want

Comment: I don't think so, because it's currently how the profile view of the Google+ app behaves. Also I can't use the header method for the recyclerview (or listview or gridview) because I use a ViewPager with tab layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design library has a component called the `AppBarLayout` to accomplish this.

Include the library:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

Wrap the `Toolbar` in an `AppBarLayout` with the scrollFlags set to 'scroll', wrap the entire layout in a `CoordinatorLayout`, and add set the layout_behavior of your scrolling view to `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"/>

      <!-- If you have tabs you can include them below the toolbar -->
      <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- If you use a ViewPager, just add the layout_behavior to it instead of the RecyclerView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: This is the exact contents of the tutorial I linked, I am able to do this without any problem. What I'm interested in, as mentioned in my question, is I want the action bar to only show when the list is already showing the first item, not immediately whenever i scroll down. Kind of like a nonsticky header to the viewpager, but scrolls in or out in sync with the first item of the recyclerview.

Comment: Your tutorial doesn't even use the design library.

Comment: Right, sorry I forgot which tutorial I linked (my question has been around for days, and I'm still searching). But I have tried using the CoordinatorLayout way as well, and it has the exact same effect as what the tutorial was trying to do. I even tried playing with the different possible layout_scrollFlags values. I was hopeful the 'enterAlwaysCollapsed' with a minHeight of 0dip would do it, but no.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on what you're looking for or post a video or something? Just having the scrollFlag set to scroll seems to do exactly as you describe.

Comment: setting layout_scrollFlags="scroll" hides it when scrolling down, but it won't show again when you scroll back the recyclerview.. that's why I'm also adding enterAlways, but that causes the toolbar to appear immediately when scrolling up, not waiting until the first item is visible.

Comment: What do you mean it won't show again? Do you mean it won't show on fling?

Comment: if you don't put enterAlways along with scroll, it never comes back after it's hidden. maybe best if you test it out yourself to see what i mean

Comment: I already did and it comes back fine. I'm curious if you have done any testing of my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to make it work. The problem was I had some other elements in my layout that I was setting to visibility=gone but didn't have scrollFlags. It was affecting how the overall stucture was supposed to work. I'm accepting your answer and giving you the bounty.